# Can I pray Salah in clothes that have touched dried urine?

Tags: salat, taharah

Assalamu Alaikum. I have a question that really needs to be answered. I'm 15 years of age don't usually pray Astaghfirullah and sometimes wet the bed. I don't completely wet it, just a little. This isn't then a big problem for me because i don't pray but now that do alhamdulilah, it's really bugging me. I usually don't tell my mum in fear of her getting cross with me. So i just sleep on it and usually don't have the sheets washed until my mum asks me to remove them from the bed to be washed. It's been maybe  a few days since i've started praying and i haven't wet the bed at all. But my sheets still haven't been washed since a few weeks ago. Does my salah still work in these clothes or do i have to change my clothes for salah until my sheets get washed?
Please please please answer quickly.

Answer (score 1):

"urine" is a najasah (impurity) which has attributes: color, odor and taste.

You should only pray in clothes that have none of these attributes: Your clothes must be tahir (pure or ritually pure) as you would be after perfroming wudu' or ghusl.
The same conditions fo purity apply on the peace of earth or area you are praying on: it must be tahir.

Further it is unhealthy to sleep in a bed with bedsheets that have dry urine.

Therefore it is essential to wash the urine from your bedsheets and clothes out.

Answer (score 0):

u dont need to wash your bed sheets unless you perform salat on your bed.

but you have to wash your clothes in holy way to perform salat even a single droplet of urine touches your cholthes directly or indirectly(from wet bedsheet)
but it is better not to sleep in dryed bed sheet with urine contamination.  because u are sleeping in an unholy place
and remember that,sleep is our short time death